# Remove duplicate lines based on a search in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file that contains thousands of lines of text as below.

> aaaa "***test*** "
>   aa "***test*** "(version 2)
>   bbbb "***test*** "(version 4)
>   bbbbb "***test1*** "(with heads)
>   abs "***test1*** "
>   absc "***test3***"

I would like to be able to remove all the duplicates based on a search and keep only the first line (in my case all lines with the same value between the quotation marks)

EDIT : More details about how I detect that a line is a duplicate of another : 
I check the value between the quotation marks. On the 3 first lines there is the value "test " between quotation marks so I want to keep the first line with this value and remove the other values. For lines 4 and 5 the value is "test1 " so I keep only line 4 and remove the other.

So after cleaning my text file would have this form

> aaaa "test "
>   bbbbb "test1 "(with heads)
>   absc "test3"

I tried to use this regular search in notepad++

> (.\".*?")

But I don't know how to use it to find duplicates and remove the other lines with the same value. I already checked other user's case but I can't found a solution.

Comment: How do you decide that `aa "test" (version 2)` is a duplicate of `aaaa "test"`? `aa` != `aaaa`. What about `aabc` - is it also a duplicate of `aaaa`? If you want to *keep only the first line*, how do you keep `bbbbb "test1" (with heads)` when it's the second one? (The first is `bbbb "test " (version 4)`.) The same question applies to `absc "test3"`, BTW. You need to be much more specific about your requirements.

Comment: Hello, I use the value between quotation marks to decide which lines are duplicate. In your example "test" is common for >aa "test" (version 2)
and >aaaa "test"


Thanks for the hint I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it in several steps.

1. append line numbers
2. put the quoted text in front
3. sort, now lines with the same quoted text are sorted behind each other, and secondly in the original sequence due to the line numbers from step 1
4. remove "duplicates"
5. remove the inserted quoted text from step 2
6. sort by the line number from step 1
7. remove the line numbers from step 1

Now the detailed explanation:

1. **append line numbers:** use Edit -> Column Editor in the first column two times

   1. insert text (some delimiter that does not occur in the file, e.g. | or : )
   2. insert numbers start with 1 increment by 1 use leading zeros

   Now each line should start with a line number and a delimiter
2. **prepend the quoted text:** use regexp replace
   *Find what:* `^([^"]*)("[^"]+")(.*)$`
   *Replace:* `\2\1\2\3`
   Now your lines should start with the text.
3. **Sort:** by using Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort ...
4. **Remove Duplicates:** with an regexp replace:
   *Find What:*  `("[^"]+")(.*)\n\1.*`
   *Replace:* `\1\2`
   Use Replace All.
5. **Remove the texts from step 2:** using regex replace
   *Find What:* `^"[^"]+"`
   *Replace with:* Nothing i.e. leave empty
6. **Sort by the original line numbers:** by using Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort ...
7. **Remove the line numbers from step 1:** using a regexp replace:
   *Find What:* `^(.*\|)`  (use \| or whatever you used in step 1 as delimiter)
   *Replace with:* Nothing i.e. leave empty